# Change registry permissions using batch

Tags: batch-file, permissions, registry

I'd like create a user called Everyone and allow Full Control for a specific registry key using a batch script regkey example:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks`  .             How I do this?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: There is a tool named subinacl. [here](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/51940)  is a small example of usage.

Comment: also, see [REGINI](https://ss64.com/nt/regini.html). More, [Take Ownership (Permission) of Registry Keys from Command Line](http://www.askvg.com/windows-tip-take-ownership-permission-of-registry-keys-from-command-line/) examples of using either `regini` or `setacl`

Comment: This might help you: [link]https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/264584/how-to-change-registry-values-or-permissions-from-a-command-line-or-a

Answer (score 1):

Solved, used SetACL and it works.

```
SetACL_x64.exe -on "<regkey>" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr "n:Everyone"
SetACL_x64.exe -on "<regkey>" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:Everyone;p:full"
```